# How to implement slide up effect and redirect to another html page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to achieve a slide up effect on the page i am on when I click a button. After the CSS effect has completed, I should then be redirected to another page(articles.html)

Currently, when i click the button, I am just redirected to the articles page. How should i go about implementing the desired outcome?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#read-articles").click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    linkLocation = 'articles.html';
    $(".body").toggleClass("boom");
    redirectPage()

  });


  function redirectPage() {
    console.log('redirect fired');
    //window.location = linkLocation;
  }
});
```

```css
.boom {
  transform: translateY(-100vw);
}

.body {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 100px;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="body">
  <div id="read-articles">boom</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What you are looking for is **[$().slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/)**. It accepts a function that will be executed post transition

Comment: use `transition-delay` css property

Comment: Thanks, @Rajesh, do I pass the redirectPage method inside the function that is executed post-transition?

Comment: Thanks @Vitorinofernandes, I am not yet sure how i can use that in this case.

Comment: @frretyy try `$().slideUp('slow', redirectPage)`. Here `'slow'` is transition speed

Comment: You should add timeout before redirect or delay something like `window.setTimeOut(yourFunction,interval)`
The problem is you are not seeing the transition because of no delay in the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery's [slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/) method for slide and use it's callback function to redirect when the sliding is finished

```js
$('#read-articles').on('click', function() {

  $('.elem').slideUp(300, function() {
    window.location = 'https://www.stackoverflow.com';
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="elem">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec quis rutrum lorem. Fusce gravida rhoncus lectus quis vulputate. Morbi ornare ex mauris, non faucibus felis interdum vitae. Nullam faucibus lorem quis pretium consectetur. Pellentesque sed risus vitae neque tempor pulvinar. Phasellus porttitor augue vitae magna dapibus fermentum. Etiam id accumsan erat. Nunc molestie finibus lectus a viverra. Pellentesque id nisi ipsum. Proin vitae magna vel tortor varius consectetur. Morbi vitae dapibus nisl. Ut nec ipsum vel quam imperdiet sodales. Duis ut iaculis enim, ac congue felis. Vestibulum egestas posuere quam, non euismod arcu mollis a. Suspendisse vel dictum neque. Fusce nec libero leo.
</div>

<button id="read-articles">Read</button>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.